# Picture in top left corner of my frontpage

Tags: titles, templates

I would like to place a sample picture/logo only in the top left corner of my front page for my thesis. I am using the Overleaf thesis doctoral template

(https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/template-for-a-masters-slash-doctoral-thesis/mkzrzktcbzfl)

I tried various ways with different packages, but they all seemed to give the error ("Option clash") and couldn't figure how to work around it. Is there a way to do it with the current packages for my template?

Thanks!

Comment: Have a look at the 'wallpaper' package. If the picture is drawn in `tikz`, have a look at section 17.13 in the pgf manual, referencing the page. There are also a few questions here on this site detailing the creation of a front page with proper picture alignment.

Comment: https://github.com/johannesbottcher/MDT-Quick-Manual/blob/master/README.md

Comment: \includegraphics{logo} right before \begin{center} (after the titlepage environment starts)

Comment: To work around an option clash (which is caused by the usage of a package which was already included in another package/class with different options) take a look at `\PassOptionsToPackage{<options>}{<package>}`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can place a picture at a specified spot on a page using `tikz` like this:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\blindtext
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \node[anchor=north west,yshift=-1.5pt,xshift=1pt]%
        at (current page.north west)
        {\includegraphics[height=5mm]{example-image}};
    \end{tikzpicture}

\blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score -2):

I don't think there is any need to load any additional package and can't imagine a option clash if extra packages are loaded correctly.

The default titlepage already shows how to include an image. If you want it at the top left corner of the text block, simply add it there.

[image: alexTitlepage]

```
\begin{titlepage}
    \includegraphics[width=5em]{example-image-1x1}
\begin{center}

\vspace*{.06\textheight}
{\scshape\LARGE \univname\par}\vspace{1.5cm} % University name
\textsc{\Large Doctoral Thesis}\\[0.5cm] % Thesis type

{\huge \bfseries \ttitle\par}\vspace{1.4cm} % Thesis title

\begin{minipage}[t]{0.4\textwidth}
\begin{flushleft} \large
\emph{Author:}\\
\href{http://www.johnsmith.com}{\authorname} % Author name - remove the \href bracket to remove the link
\end{flushleft}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.4\textwidth}
\begin{flushright} \large
\emph{Supervisor:} \\
\href{http://www.jamessmith.com}{\supname} % Supervisor name - remove the \href bracket to remove the link  
\end{flushright}
\end{minipage}\\[3cm]

\vfill

\large \textit{A thesis submitted in fulfillment of the requirements\\ for the degree of \degreename}\\[0.3cm] % University requirement text
\textit{in the}\\[0.4cm]
\groupname\\\deptname\\[2cm] % Research group name and department name

\vfill

{\large \today}\\[4cm] % Date
%\includegraphics{Logo} % University/department logo - uncomment to place it

\vfill
\end{center}
\end{titlepage}
```