# What is the simplest way of adding a PNG to this part of the document?

Tags: floats, positioning

I'd like to know how i can add a figure to the part of the document that is outlined in red!
Thanks in advance.

[image]

Edit: This is how my document looks like:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[left=3cm,top=3cm,right=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{times}

\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
    UNIVERSIDADE FEDERAL DE ITAJUBÁ
    
    Instituto de Sistemas Elétricos e Energia
\vspace{5cm}

%-------------------PARTICIPANTES-----------------------
Camila Carvalho Ribeiro - 2020023623

Filipe Vilani do Espírito Santo - 2020002614  

Lucas Avelar Maffra - 2020003961

Samuel Lucas dos Santos Junior - 2020001798

Gabriel Bortoletto Molz - 2019003459
%-------------------------------------------------------

\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I edited the post with the TeX code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Three methods in one example:

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,array,lipsum}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\begin{document}

% Method 1: one minipage

\noindent
\includegraphics[valign=c,width=.15\linewidth]{example-image}%
\begin{minipage}[c]{.7\linewidth}\centering
    UNIVERSIDADE FEDERAL DE ITAJUBÁ\par
    Instituto de Sistemas Elétricos e Energia
\end{minipage}

% Method 1: two minipages

\vfill
\noindent
\begin{minipage}[c]{.15\linewidth}\centering
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}%
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[c]{.7\linewidth}\centering
    UNIVERSIDADE FEDERAL DE ITAJUBÁ\par
    Instituto de Sistemas Elétricos e Energia
\end{minipage}

 
\vfill
% Method 3: three cells of one table

\tabcolsep0em % no cell padding
\noindent\begin{tabular}[t]{p{.15\linewidth}m{.7\linewidth}p{.15\linewidth}} 
\centering\includegraphics[valign=c,width=\linewidth]{example-image}& 
    \centering
    UNIVERSIDADE FEDERAL DE ITAJUBÁ\par
    Instituto de Sistemas Elétricos e Energia & \\
\end{tabular}

\vfill
\lipsum[1-3]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Two different packages (answers) can be used for this question.

1. `tikz`
2. `eso-pic`

Accepted answer using with `tikz` package can be found [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/373909/picture-in-top-left-corner-of-my-frontpage).

To be use `eso-pic` package you should first add this package into your preamble as:

```
\usepackage{graphix}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
```

`\usepackage{graphix}` must be added before the `eso-pic` package.

Then you should define your coordinates to add the image into your document as given below with the `\AddToShipoutPicture` command.

`\AddToShipoutPicture*{\put(0,800){\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{your_image}}}`

*Hint: `\put(0,0)` will point the bottom left of your page.*

Comment: @washburn961 if it is true or helpful please do not forget to vote the answer.